# Assigning value to multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to assign a value to associative array without creating another dimension with numerical array?

$champion[$row['Champion']]['New'] = $row['New'];

Array like this

[image]

'New' How could I access this value?

```
$champion=array();

                    $champions_table= $conn->prepare("SELECT Champion, New, Passive, Q, Q2, W, W2, E, E2, R, R2 FROM champions Where Patch_No = ? ORDER BY ID ASC");
                    $champions_table->bind_param('s', $Patch_No);
                    $champions_table->execute();
                    $champions_table_result = $champions_table->get_result();

while($row = $champions_table_result->fetch_assoc()){
                        //Getting General Changes
                        $champion[$row['Champion']]['New'] = $row['New'];
}
```

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, but you can assign a new value to an array by `$existingarray['new'] = $whateveryouwant`

Comment: @mattslone how can I retrieve said value? I've tried doing sth like echo $champions[$row['Champion']]['New']; with no success

Comment: no I just want to know if 'New' value is 0 or 1 for that specyfic champion so echo $champion['Something']['New'] and i want to get 1 or 0 from this

Answer (score 0):

To get all values assigned.

```
foreach ( $champion as $key => $value) {
    echo "Champion : ".$key." Value: ".$value['New']." <br />\n";
}
```

if you know Champion name

```
echo $champion['championname']['New'] <br />\n";
```

example

```
echo $champion['Blitzcrank']['New'] <br />\n";
```

If you want a 3 Dimension array slightly expanded to more easily see how it's assigned to

```
while($row = $champions_table_result->fetch_assoc()){
        $value = $row['Champion'];
        $champion['Champion'][$value]= array('New' => $row['New']);
}
```

get the value

```
echo $champion['Champion']['Blitzcrank']['New'] <br />\n";
```

Comment: echo $champion['championname']['New'] i've tried that and i do know the name of the champion and i get undentified index

Comment: @Higeath: can you please give a respond ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a result from your database:

`$row = array('Champion' => 'champ', 'New' => '1');`

This should work:

```
$champion[$row['Champion']]['New'] = $row['New'];
echo $champion[$row['Champion']]['New'];
```

And should output `1`

Comment: OP using `$champion[$row['Champion']]['New'] = $row['New'];` so  `$champion['?']` becomes the value of  `$row['Champion']` !!

Comment: Right.. does my answer not reflect that? I'm just echoing whatever the current record from the database is.

Comment: this would only work inside the loop .( `$row` valid inside loop) OP wants the  value after the loop e.g. `echo $champion['Blitzcrank']['New'];` your example will work like `echo $champion['champ']['New'];` And that is the same as my answer.